# About understanding partition lease expiration

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I have an event hub with 4 partitions and 2 consumer groups. I have 2 webjobs that read the data using an `EventProcessor`. Both for a different consumer group

I have configured the event processors like this:

```
        var host = new EventProcessorHost(
            Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            configurationManager.EventHubConfiguration.Path,
            configurationManager.EventHubConfiguration.ConsumerGroupName,
            configurationManager.EventHubConfiguration.ListenerConnectionString,
            configurationManager.StorageConfiguration.ConnectionString)
        {
            PartitionManagerOptions = new PartitionManagerOptions
            {
                AcquireInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                RenewInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                LeaseInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
            }
        };

        var options = EventProcessorOptions.DefaultOptions;
        options.MaxBatchSize = 250;

        await host.RegisterEventProcessorFactoryAsync(new PlanCareEventProcessorFactory(telemetryClient, configurationManager), options);
        return host;
```

In my EventProcessor I keep track of the progress (some methods skipped to keep it short and readable):

```
internal class PlanCareEventProcessor : IEventProcessor
{
    public Task OpenAsync(PartitionContext context)
    {
        namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(configurationManager.EventHubConfiguration.ManagerConnectionString);

        if (namespaceManager == null)
            return;

        var currentSeqNo = context.Lease.SequenceNumber;
        var lastSeqNo = namespaceManager.GetEventHubPartition(context.EventHubPath, context.ConsumerGroupName, context.Lease.PartitionId).EndSequenceNumber;
        var delta = lastSeqNo - currentSeqNo;

        var msg = $"Last processed seqnr for partition {context.Lease.PartitionId}: {currentSeqNo} of {lastSeqNo} in consumergroup '{context.ConsumerGroupName}' (lag: {delta})";
        telemetryClient.TrackTrace(new TraceTelemetry(msg, SeverityLevel.Information));
        telemetryClient.TrackMetric(new MetricTelemetry($"Partition_Lag_{context.Lease.PartitionId}_{context.ConsumerGroupName}", delta));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task ProcessEventsAsync(PartitionContext context, IEnumerable<EventData> events)
    {
        progressCounter++;

        ...

        await LogProgress(context);
    }

    private async Task LogProgress(PartitionContext context)
    {
        if (progressCounter >= 100)
        {
            await CheckPointAsync(context);
            progressCounter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I noticed a difference in the webjobs when it comes to how often `OpenAsync` and `CloseAsync` are called. For one of the consumer groups this is about every half hour while for the other one it is several times a minute.

Since both webjobs use the same code and are running on the same app plan, what could be the reason for this?

It bothers me because checkpointing using `await CheckPointAsync(context)` is almost never done for one of the webjobs since it does not reach the threshold before the lease is gone.

Comment: Do you try to detect/check the CloseReason in CloseAsync method?

Comment: To be honest, I didn't. I will keep an eye on it!